# Multiple table inheritance Rails and activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, class-table-inheritance

I'm trying to implement Multiple Table Inheritance with ActiveRecord. Looks like all the available gems are pretty old. Am I missing something? Is there any "native" way to implement this with activerecord?
I'm using Rails 3.2.3 and activerecord 3.2.1

Comment: There is a lot of confusion amongst developers relating to exact differences between multi-table-inheritance vs single-table-inheritance vs class-table-inheritance.

I think it's important to determine what you believe you're referring to before I can properly give you an answer.

This is definitely a topic of interest for me so please post an update if you have any newer information to offer.

:)

Answer (score 2):

#### Rails 6.1+ delegated type

Rails 6.1 added a "native" way to implement Multiple Table Inheritance via `delegated type`.

See [the corresponding PR for details](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39341).

> With this approach, the "superclass" is a concrete class that is represented by its own table, where all the superclass attributes that are shared amongst all the "subclasses" are stored. And then each of the subclasses have their own individual tables for additional attributes that are particular to their implementation. This is similar to what's called multi-table inheritance in Django, but instead of actual inheritance, this approach uses delegation to form the hierarchy and share responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Single Table Inheritance (where each Car and Truck share one database)

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord
end

class Car < Vehicle
end

class Truck < Vehicle
end
```

In your case you are not sharing the database but rather the functions. You should then write a module and include it in each model

```
class Car < ActiveRecord
  extend VehicleFinders
end

class Truck < ActiveRecord
  extend VehicleFinders
end

module VehicleFinders
  def find_purchased
    #...
  end
end
```

So in `extend` module's method are class method on that calling class.`include` module's methods are instance method for object of calling class

This might be a good read for you http://raysrashmi.com/2012/05/05/enhance-rails-models

Comment: new link is http://raysrashmi.com/2012/05/05/enhance-rails-models without .html at the end